# A simple module is necessarily the socle of its injective hull?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, injective-module

According to the wikipedia page on [injective hulls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_hull)  "a simple module is necessarily the socle of its injective hull". It is clear to me that why a simple module is a subset to the socle of of its injective hull, but I cannot prove the equality. Can anyone help me with that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extension $M\hookrightarrow X$ is *essential* if any nonzero submodule of $X$ intersects $M$ nontrivially. If this is the case and if $M$ is moreover simple, then it follows that any simple submodule of $X$ equals $M$. Hence $$\text{soc}(X)=\sum\limits_{\substack{N\subset X\\\text{simple}}} N=M.$$
Note that the injectivity of $I$ is not important here.